# React Modal in Type Script

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jsx

I'm using the react-modal to make a modal in a Typescript React set up.

This is the file for the modal:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactModal from 'react-modal';

class MyModal extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor () {
    super();
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
    };

    this.handleOpenModal = this.handleOpenModal.bind(this);
    this.handleCloseModal = this.handleCloseModal.bind(this);
  }

  handleOpenModal () {
    this.setState({ showModal: true });
  }

  handleCloseModal () {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });
  }

  public modalState () {
    const stateRef = this.state;
    return stateRef["showModal"];
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleOpenModal}>Trigger Modal</button>
        <ReactModal
          isOpen={this.modalState()}
          contentLabel="Minimal Modal Example"
        >
          <button onClick={this.handleCloseModal}>Close Modal</button>
        </ReactModal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And this is how I am using it:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {UndoRedo} from './undo-redo';
import * as MyModal from './my-modal';

export class Header extends React.PureComponent<any, {}> {
  public render() {
    return (
      <header className="header">
        Header
        <UndoRedo/>
        <MyModal/>
      </header>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the error I am getting:

> ERROR in ./src/components/header/index.tsx (11,10): error TS2604: JSX
>   element type 'MyModal' does not have any construct or call signatures.

I looked around and didn't see anything that took a class based approach with the same issue. What I did see seemed to based on a missing render function. I did try making render public and that didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error message means you are importing it improperty. You should export your class and import it properly

```
export default class MyModal extends ....
```

and then when you import it

```
import MyModal from './my-modal';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try importing React Modal in the following way

```
import ReactModal = require('react-modal');
```